# Long to String return null (jFrame)

Tags: java, string, jframe, long-integer

I'm am trying to make a timer, using currentTimeMillis, in the jFrame, but when i click the button that returns the elapsed time, the returned value is null,  neither in the console (see this [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnDLi.png)) the value is normal.
In the moment, like you see in the code, I'm using toString, I tried with the valueOf, but I receive the error "long cannot be converted to string".
He is 'piece' of my code:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public long startTime;
long elapsedSeconds;
long elapsedTime;    
public long secondsDisplay; // Segundos |
public long elapsedMinutes; // Minutos   } os três principais
public long elapsedHours;   // Horas    |
String ShowSeg = Long.toString(secondsDisplay);
String ShowMin = Long.toString(elapsedMinutes);
String ShowHour = Long.toString(elapsedHours);
/**
 * Creates new form SSMFrame
 */
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//*A long code resided here*//                     
private void StoCountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
elapsedSeconds = elapsedTime / 1000;
secondsDisplay = elapsedSeconds % 60;
elapsedMinutes = elapsedSeconds / 60;
elapsedHours = elapsedMinutes / 60;
    ShowETseg.setText(ShowSeg);
    ShowETmin.setText(ShowMin);
    ShowEThour.setText(ShowHour);
```

Comment: You need to create and post with your question a valid [mcve] program.

Comment: You will also want to learn and follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), since this will make your code easier for others to follow. Variable names should all begin with a lower-case letter.

Comment: I tested in another project, and is fine, as I "said" the problem is with the conversion Long to String, that is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set the value of string variables after you get the time
so change your code to be like this :

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public long startTime;
    long elapsedSeconds;
    long elapsedTime;    
    public long secondsDisplay; // Segundos |
    public long elapsedMinutes; // Minutos   } os três principais
    public long elapsedHours;   // Horas    |


//initialize the string variables to empty strings 
    String ShowSeg = "";//
    String ShowMin = "";//
    String ShowHour = "";//
    /**
     * Creates new form SSMFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //*A long code resided here*//                     
    private void StoCountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    elapsedSeconds = elapsedTime / 1000;
    secondsDisplay = elapsedSeconds % 60;
    elapsedMinutes = elapsedSeconds / 60;
    elapsedHours = elapsedMinutes / 60;


//set the strings to their long equivalents
ShowSeg = Long.toString(secondsDisplay);
ShowMin = Long.toString(elapsedMinutes );
ShowHour = Long.toString(elapsedHours);


        ShowETseg.setText(ShowSeg);
        ShowETmin.setText(ShowMin);
        ShowEThour.setText(ShowHour);
```